# How to create index on array element in indexeddb

Tags: indexeddb

I have an object,

```
var _data = {
        teacher : {
            name : "Mack",
            subject : "Maths"
        },
        Student : [{
            name : "Alex",
            stud_id : 1
        },{
            name : "Jack",
            stud_id : 2
        },{
            name : "Mark",
            stud_id : 3
        }]

}
```

I want to create index on stud_id, how can I create?

Answer (score 4):

What I would do that is to have two separate object stores inside of your database, one which represents `teachers` and one which represents `students`.

Then I'd store a `teacher` object like:

```
{
    name: 'John Smith',
    subject: 'Maths',
    students: [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

Then I'd have a store for `students` like:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jane Doe'
}
```

I'd then have an `id` key path in both stores (autogenerated or not, depending on whether it syncs somewhere) so you have a unique identifier of what the data is.

Finally you can create an `index` on the `students` property of a teacher and set the [`multiEntry` flag to `true`](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-multientry) so that it is known to be an array and you can query the object store on it as an array, see [here](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/09/indexeddb-multientry-explained.html) for more info on `multiEntry` indexes.

**Note: At time of writing IE10 & IE11 do not support `multiEntry` indexes in IndexedDB.**

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible. Element of keyPath must be string.

Comment: If I want to apply the index on array element which is string. In the object above Student array has name property, can I apply index on name, and how?